# Is there a specific way to make a maze layout in Java?

Tags: java

I have tried making a maze layout in java but I keep getting errors. I have fixed the simple errors but I cannot get the other errors to go away. Every time I change the code like, even the menu won't show up.
Here are some of the errors I have.

```
Main.java:53: error: '}' expected
        "\033[40mblack\033[49m";
                               ^
Main.java:54: error: not a statement
        "\033[41mred\033[49m"};
        ^
Main.java:54: error: ';' expected
        "\033[41mred\033[49m"};
                             ^
Main.java:59: error: <identifier> expected
  custom.initializeOptions();
                          ^
Main.java:60: error: <identifier> expected
  System.out.println("Enter integer choice for width: ")
                    ^
Main.java:60: error: illegal start of type
  System.out.println("Enter integer choice for width: ")
                     ^
Main.java:62: error: <identifier> expected
  mapheight = custom.intInput(20,100);
           ^
MazeLayout.java:6: error: invalid method declaration; return type required
  public Mazelayout()
         ^
MazeLayout.java:63: error: <identifier> expected
    System.out.print("\033[0m");
                    ^
MazeLayout.java:63: error: illegal start of type
    System.out.print("\033[0m");
                     ^
MazeLayout.java:65: error: class, interface, or enum expected
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a look at [ask] and then [edit] you question accordingly. Right now there is no telling how anyone could help you with no code, no errors and barely any expected behavior provided.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Right now, we don't even know what code you're using, let alone what frameworks, libraries, and the like you're working with. Are you using ASCII to display this layout, or a GUI? If the latter, Swing or JavaFX? We need more information in order to help you.

Comment: We need to see what is causing those errors. Most likely the errors start with a typo or other simple mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide a return type for a method (the first error) or it is considered a constructor.

The rest is probably a syntax error a bit later from which the compiler cannot figure out how to get back on track.

In Other words - your source is broken.  Consider studying class definitions again.